# Asp.net page lifecycle-specific global variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Surely it must be a common problem but I can't find an easy way to do this.

Is there a way to share a global variable (say a class which is expensive to instantiate) through the life cycle of an asp.net webform, without having to pass the handle to every single component of the page?

If I just create a static variable, it will be accessible by all threads in the app domain (problem: my class is not thread safe), and it will be hard to ensure that every page works on a recent copy (I want to cache the class through every step of the life cycle of the page, but I want a new instance every time a new page is called).

The alternative is to pass a handle through each control in the page, but between the master page, the page itself, and all the user controls, it makes the code quite hairy.

I was wondering if there wasn't an elegant solution to store a class in some place which is accessible only to the thread executing this particular page (including all sub user controls)?

Any suggestion welcome!
Thanks
Charles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simple answer: the Items container. It is available for the lifetime of a single request and then it is automatically destroyed. You can wrap it in a property to have what you want:

```
 public class Foo {

   const string SOMEKEY = "_somekey";

   public static string SingleRequestVariable
   {
      get
      {
          return (string)HttpContext.Current.Items[SOMEKEY];   
      }
      set
      {
          HttpContext.Current.Items.Add( SOMEKEY, value );
      }
   }
 }
```

and then

```
Foo.SingleRequestVariable = "bar"; // somewhere
...
string val = Foo.SingleRequestVariable; // yet somewhere else
```

Comment: Nice solution! Effectively I can have a static function Foo.Current which goes into httpcontext, checks if an instance of foo is already there, otherwise creates one and add it, and returns this instance. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Just because others might stumble on this answer... if in the variable set method, you use  HttpContext.Current.Items[SOMEKEY] = value;  then that will create an item if one is not there or reset its value if it is already there.  No need to recode that when the dictionary class already does it for you.